# Change text of textview in custom toolbar in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-toolbar

I am trying to create custom toolbar. I followed this [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59722/toolbar-title-set-center-align). And i could achive toolbar change, but i cant change toolbar text. Here is what i am doing

```
var toolbarTop = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar_top);
var titleTextView = toolbarTop.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.toolbar_title);
titleTextView.Text = title;
```

But title is not changed. What is wrong here?

BTW: I am changing title on every new navigation to different pages. Not on activity create.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it in "OnCreate". Do it here

```
    public override void OnAttachedToWindow()
    {
       base.OnAttachedToWindow();
       Title = "Title Text";
    }
```

Comment: Toolbar is replaced with custom one. Title is not working anymore. I need to change text of textview in custom toolbar

Comment: Try to change the text view but in OnAttachedToWindow function

Comment: i am working in xamarin forms. I need to change text whenever i navigate to another page in Xamarin Forms. In android it is always 1 activity.

Comment: I am confused. FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar_top); seems like pure Android code, not Forms code. Where do you call that? in PCL?

Comment: I am calling it in Activity from PCL. I implemented service so i can call this method from PCL whenever i need

Comment: Where can I grab your code to help you. Can you share this piece?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Title = "Title Text";
```

Or maybe this will help:
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/Toolbar/

Comment: Toolbar is replaced with custom one. Title is not working anymore. I need to change text of textview in custom toolbar